# notifyDataSetChanged() in BaseAdapter

Tags: android

**This is my code, here I am trying to remove the item from Arraylist and trye to update the layout item with notifyDataSetChanged.**

```
public class GroupContactListingAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<ContactListDto> groupListDto = new ArrayList<ContactListDto>();
    private Activity context;
    public static ArrayList<String> selectList;

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Assigning the parameter
     * 
     * @param mContext1
     *            Getting the context of the class
     * @param contactList
     *            list to be display
     * @param value
     *            if 0 all, if 1 unblocked and 2 blocked
     * @param isContactList
     *            if 1 then contact list and if 0 search contact list
     */
    public GroupContactListingAdapter(Activity mContext1,
            ArrayList<ContactListDto> contactList) {
        this.context = mContext1;
        this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext1
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (this.groupListDto != null) {
            this.groupListDto.clear();
        }
        this.groupListDto = contactList;
        selectList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return groupListDto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return groupListDto.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_listing_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.group_name);
            viewHolder.relative = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.group_layout);
            viewHolder.deleteContacts = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_group_contact_delete);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.deleteContacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.deleteContacts
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Helper.printLogD(" deleting position is " + position);
                        selectList.add(groupListDto.get(position)
                                .getContactId());
                        groupListDto.remove(groupListDto.get(position));

                        notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                });

        viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(groupListDto.get(position)
                .getContactFullName());
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            viewHolder.relative.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            viewHolder.relative.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.list_even_color));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Following error occur

```
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434): null
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at com.hazemedia.stewdent.client.android.ui.adapter.GroupContactListingAdapter$ViewHolder.access$4(GroupContactListingAdapter.java:133)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at com.hazemedia.stewdent.client.android.ui.adapter.GroupContactListingAdapter.getView(GroupContactListingAdapter.java:94)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1428)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1339)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1279)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7321)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1217)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1995)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
12-18 11:43:01.895: E/ListView(24434):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line is 94 in your code?

Answer (score 3):

**This problem was created because I was not taging the viewHolder in convertView instance..**

```
convertView .setTag(viewHolder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this type of code may be help to you,

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_listing_item, null);
        mViewHolder. nameTextView = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        mViewHolder.relative = (RelativeLayout) convertView .findViewById(R.id.group_layout);
        mViewHolder.deleteContacts = (Button) convertView .findViewById(R.id.btn_group_contact_delete);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    deleteContacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    deleteContacts .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Helper.printLogD(" deleting position is " + position);
            selectList.add(groupListDto.get(position) .getContactId());
            groupListDto.remove(groupListDto.get(position));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    nameTextView.setText(groupListDto.get(position) .getContactFullName());
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        relative.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources() .getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        relative.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources() .getColor(R.color.list_even_color));
    }
    return convertView;
}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView nameTextView;
    RelativeLayout relative;
    Button deleteContacts;
}
```

Comment: you are not add mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
in getview thats why this error occur.

Comment: but it gives nullpointer error because of constructor just only one time initialize but getview method is everytime initialize till row count thats why just put into getview and see result